# React ref anti-pattern for Popups

Tags: reactjs, typescript, design-patterns, anti-patterns

Recently I've found myself implementing a ref based pattern that seems to go against [react documentation advice](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs).

The pattern goes like this :

```
type Callback = () => void;
type CallbackWrapper = {callback : Callback}

interface IWarningPopupRef{
    warn : (callback : Callback) => void;
}

interface IWarningPopupProps{
    warningText : string;
}

const WarningPopup = forwardRef<IWarningPopupRef, IWarningPopupProps>(
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);
    const [callback, setCallback] = useState<CallbackWrapper | null>(null);
    const warn = (callback : Callback) => {
        setShow(true);
        setCallback({callback});
    }
    const acceptWarning = () => {
        setShow(false);
        setCallback(null);
        if(callback != null) callback.callback();
    }
    useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
        warn
    }));
    (props, ref) => {
        return (
            <div style={{
                visibility:(show)?"visible":"hidden"
            }}>
                {props.warningText}
                <button onClick={acceptWarning}>Accept</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
)

const Component : React.FC = props => {
    const warningPopupRef = useRef<IWarningPopupRef>(null);
    const doDangerButton = () => {
        warningPopupRef.current!.warn(() => {
            doDangerAction();
        });
    }
    return (
        <button onClick={doDangerButton}>Dangerous button</button>
        <WarningPopup ref={warningPopupRef} 
            warningText="Warning ! This is a dangerous button !"/>
    )
}
```

If I were to follow react documentation advice and lift the state to the parent component I'd have this :

```
interface IWarningPopupProps{
    warningText : string;
    show : boolean;
    onWarningAccept : () => void;
}

const WarningPopup : React.FC<IWarningPopupProps> = props => {
    return (
        <div style={{
            visibility:(props.show)?"visible":"hidden"
        }}>
            {props.warningText}
            <button onClick={props.onWarningAccept}>Accept</button>
        </div>
    )
} 

const Component : React.FC = props => {
    const [warningPopupShow, setWarningPopupShow] = useState(false);
    const doDangerButton = () => {
        setWarningPopupShow(true);
    }
    const acceptWarning = () => {
        setWarningPopupShow(false);
        doDangerAction();
    }
    return (
        <button onClick={doDangerButton}>Dangerous button</button>
        <WarningPopup warningText="Warning ! This is a dangerous button !"
            show={warningPopupShow}
            onWarningAccept={acceptWarning}/>
    )
}
```

Now I don't do the above because I'm concerned about abstraction leakage and my parent component having to handle both the state it was created to manipulate and this popup state.

My reasoning is that the popup is an interruption of navigation flow and as such should be handled in it's own context.

Am I laying a trap for my future self with this (anti-)pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I approve the second, more "React-y", solution because:

- It makes sense that your parent holds the shown state. In later uses, you might be really happy to have more flexibility over popup control flow.
- Your original pattern is much more complex to read and to maintain as you expose an imperative API which is less obvious and usually require additional documentation. Instead, props are simple standard React, are much more predictable and testable.
- Refs impose the parent/user to bypass React's life cycle by forcing them to check that the ref contains an element at the expected time.

Finally, you can adjust your popup in a way that is convenient to use for you:

```
const Component : React.FC = props => {
    const [warningPopupShow, setWarningPopupShow] = useState(false);
    return (
        <button onClick={doDangerButton}>Dangerous button</button>
        <WarningPopup warningText="Warning ! This is a dangerous button !"
            show={warningPopupShow}
            onShow={setWarningPopupShow} // Simply separate "shown" updates from
                                         // acceptation action in the popup
            onWarningAccept={doDangerAction}/>
    )
}
```

Simple, functional, idiomatic.